# Can firebird database connect to other databases using like linked server in SQL Server?

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

I know that SQL Server has linked server that allow it to connect to other database and execute query. Now I am using firebird. I wonder if firebird has its "linked server" to access other databases. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebird doesn't have a linked server feature. There is a limited method for accessing other Firebird databases (either remote or locally) using [`EXECUTE STATEMENT`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-psql-execstmt-onexternal), however this only supports Firebird database, and you need to provide the data source information on each invocation.

Comment: This feature is enough for me. Thanks!